# ZFC vs second-order arithmetic: Help me understand the distinction explicitly!

Tags: logic, set-theory

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic): Second-order arithmetic can also be seen as a weak version of set theory in which every element is either a natural number or a set of natural numbers. Although it is much weaker than Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory, second-order arithmetic can prove essentially all of the results of classical mathematics expressible in its language.)

I know that ZFC proves second-order arithmetic but I would like to understand in exactly what regard second-order arithmetic is "weaker". Is there any forumalted theorem up to this date that only makes sense in ZFC and cannot be forumalted in the language of second-order arithmetic by just associating sets with sets of natural numbers? Or is the distinction only interesting in a proof-theoretic context? (i.e. *in principle* ZFC allows sets that are not just sets of natural numbers, but all reasonably formulated propositions can always be reformulated in second-order arithmetic) If the latter is true, then what would be an explicit example of a construction that goes further than second-order arithmetic?

Thank you!

(This consideration was inspired by the question whether there is a function of natural numbers in ZFC that has a faster growth rate than all fuctions that can be formulated in the language of second-order arithmetic. I hope that is not a stupid question to ask.)

Comment: Some examples in Stephen Simpson, Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic (Cambridge UP, 2nd ed 2009) [see page 23].

Comment: Borel determinacy can be proved in ZFC and expressed in second-order arithmetic (at least when restricted to the Baire space). It is not provable in second order arithmetic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! I see that I grossly overestimated the power of $Z_2$ and, in general, of arithmetic expressions. Please correct me if I am wrong, but by following the trail of references, I think I understand now that for every natural number $n$ and every finite-order arithmetic $Z_n$, we can find statements in $ZFC$ that are neither expressable nor provable in $Z_n$.

Comment: Note that "second-order arithmetic" is also used to refer to the second-order version of Peano arithmetic, $\mathsf{PA}_2$. This is a theory in second-order logic, in contrast to $\mathsf{Z}_2$ which (despite the name) uses first-order logic. $\mathsf{PA_2}$ is complete and indeed fully categorical, and so e.g. entails ("proves" isn't a great word to use here) lots of things about natural numbers which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ doesn't such as $\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$.

Comment: In 1st order PA, we cannot discuss subsets of $\mathbb N$, but only formulas that cut out the desired subsets. In 2nd order arithmetic, we are allowed to directly discuss subsets of $\mathbb N$, but not subsets whose elements are subsets, or to mix, like a set whose elements can be either subsets or natural numbers.  ZFC has no problem  to form any kind of sets.

Answer (score 0):

Z₂ is all about countable mathematics. For example, In Z₂ we can't even express:
"Every vector space has a basis"
But we can express and prove this:
"Every countable vector space has a basis"
And there are a lot of similar examples.
So, ZFC is stronger than Z₂, because in ZFC, we can talk about arbitrary sets, but in Z₂, we can't.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).